# "Maximum Sum mod M" ranges in an array: sum and count

Tags: c++

## Problem

Given an array **A = a0,a1,...an**, with size up to **N ≤ 10^5**, and **0 ≤ a<sub>i</sub> ≤ 10^9.**
And a number **0 < M ≤ 10^9.**

The task is to find the maximum **∑(k=i, j) a<sub>k</sub> % M = (a<sub>i</sub> + a<sub>i+1</sub> + a<sub>(i+2)</sub> + ⋯ + a<sub>(j−1)</sub> + a<sub>(j)</sub>) % M**, and how many different **range(i,j)** get that sum.

The complexity has to be less than **O(N^2)**, the latter is too slow.

## Example

**N** = 3, **M** = 5

**A** = {2, 4, 3}

The **Maximum Sum mod M** is **4** and there are **2** ranges, which are **a<sub>0</sub> to a<sub>2</sub>** and **a<sub>1</sub>**

## My attempt

Let's define **s[j] = (a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub> + ... + a<sub>j</sub>) % M** so if you want the best sum that ends in **j** you have to choose an **s[i] i < j** that s[i] is the smallest sum higher than you.

Because if **s[i] > s[j]; s[i] = M - K; K < M - s[j]** then the result sum range will be **(s[j]-s[i]+M) % M = (s[j] + K) % M** and because **K < M - s[j]** it will increase the result **mod M**, and as **s[j]** gets closer to **s[j]** it will increase the result **mod M**.

Comment: Please, be more specific about what you mean with "consecutive range", giving an example would be the best. And please, post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Currently the answer to your question is "Yes." That's about as useless an answer as it gets, so I recommend tightening up the bounds of your question. Perhaps add your own attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: How would you find that in an array with four elements? Five, six, *n*, *n+1*?

Comment: Hint: It has to do with dynamic programming.

Comment: @eguaio Sorry i have already edit my post. Could you bring me some help?

Comment: @user4581301 That's on me, I'm new and didn't know how to ask, it's more clear?

Comment: @greybeard I put the limits of the problem

Comment: @FeiXiang Yes, I were thinking about it, but I don't know what states it has, and how could  save the posibles sums

Comment: Another hint: Define `dp[i]` as the maximum sum of a subarray that ends at the `i`th element. How can we express `dp[i]` in terms of `dp[some j less than i]` and the `i`th element in the array?

Comment: Much, much better, but not yet a programming question. If you have run your attempt through on pen and paper and it works, translate it to code. If the code works, awesome! You're done! If the code does not work you are in good position to ask a Stack Overflow question because you now have a software-related question. If the attempt does not work with pen and paper, you are in a rougher spot with respect to Stack Overflow. You may find more love at [mathematics.se], but if you add in your run-though with a focused  question relating to the logic, you may get a good answer here.

Comment: @FeiXiang Okey I think I get it, but that only answer the first question, but how many times you max(dp[i]) appears?

Comment: @user4581301 Well I think I have the idea but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: @greybeard It was M, I already correct it

Comment: You're kind of overthinking this. If we want to compute `dp[i]`, the best sum that ends at the `i`th element, the subarray could either include the `i-1`th element, or it must start at the `i`th element. Think about how we can compute the result for these two cases. Ignore the mod `m` stuff for now.

Comment: Oh wait, I misread the problem... I thought it was asking for the `max(sum) mod m`, instead of the `max(sum mod m)`. That makes it a little harder, and I'll have to think about it more.

Comment: I think you can simply count how many times we encounter a value that is equal to the best that we have seen. We can reset the counter every time we update the variable storing the best sum.

Comment: @FeiXiang But you have to save how many times apeear every one, because when you found a new maximum, you had to count how many times you could do it. But I already solve it with a map. Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is my attemp, first you have to have to calculate all the sums that starts from 0 and end in a index i, then you can search the smaller value grater than you fast by searching the value with a binary search that the map already have (lower_bound), and count how many time you could do sum with the value that you found. You have to keep the sum somewhere to count how many time you could do it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#define optimizar_io ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);
using namespace std;

const int LN = 1e5;
long long N, M, num[LN];
map < long long, int > sum;

int main() {

    optimizar_io

        cin >> N >> M;

    sum[0]++;

    long long cont = 0, tmax = 0, res = 1, val;
    map < long long, int > :: iterator best;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cin >> num[i];
        cont = (cont + num[i]) % M;
        if (tmax == cont)
            res += sum[0];
        if (tmax < cont)
            tmax = cont, res = sum[0];
        best = sum.lower_bound(cont + 1);
        if (best != sum.end())
        {
            val = cont - (*best).first + M;
            if (tmax == val)
                res += (*best).second;
            if (tmax < val)
                tmax = val, res = (*best).second;
        }
        sum[cont]++;
    }

    cout << tmax << " " << res;

    return 0;
}
```